# Need a SDK/API to read electrical network from GE Small world database

Tags: sdk, gis

We have elelectrical network in GE small world. We need to export data from GE small world to SQL files along with the geometry to import to our inhouse GIS application. Is there any API/SDK available to read the data from the GE small world database?

Need some API/SDK to read the electrical network along with the geometry and other attributes from GE small world database.